# How to show vector features in OpenLayers after hiding it?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, style, filter

I did change some vector features style (through check-boxes) using style property :

```
var features = layer.features;

for( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
  //features[i].style = { visibility: 'hidden' };
    features[i].style = 'none'; 
}

layer.redraw();
```

But now if I check the box again, it supposed to display again but nothing happens! I tried:

```
     features[i].style = 'block'; 
OR
     features[i].style = 'delete';
```

then redraw the layer.. but this doesn't work

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 3):

It's my understanding that you need to change the display property of style:

```
features[i].style.display = 'none'; // hide
```

or

```
features[i].style.display = ''; // show. Set to anything but 'none'
```

Then you need to do a redraw on the layer after changing the vectors in it:

```
affectedlayer.redraw();
```

Of course.. I'm having trouble with this now too ( which is how I found this question). If I change it manually in the debugger it seems to work ( zooming in to cause a redraw) but in code it's not working for me at the moment.

Update: Too funny... I went back and looked with new eyes.. was missing the .style bit in some copy-paste edits! Glad I found your question ;)

Comment: in my experience this approach could fail in some cases when style is null. Similar solution provided by Rayiez works fine in such situations.

Answer (score 2):

To hide features

```
    for( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
      features[i].style = { display: 'none' };
    }
    layer.redraw();
```

To display back the hidden features

```
    for( var i = 0; i < features.length; i++ ) {
      features[i].style = null;
    }
    layer.redraw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it another way:

to hide:

```
vectorLayer.features[0].style.fillOpacity = 0;
vectorLayer.redraw();
```

to show:

```
vectorLayer.features[0].style.fillOpacity = 1;
vectorLayer.redraw();
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: could fail if style is null...