# Set style from features of layer to hidden?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, style

Is it possible to set the style to hidden of certain parts of a layer of the map? The API documentation does not seems to have any property for it?

I tried to add the following:

```
var locatusObject = new ol.layer.Vector ({
  source: locatusSource,
  maxResolution: 14,
  style: styleFunction
});
function styleFunction(feature,resolution) {
style = [new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: changeStrokeStyle(),
                fill: changeFillStyle(),
                //opacity:0,
                //visible:none
                //visibility:hidden
            })];

return style;
}
```

None seem to work?

**EDIT**

Oke, it seems to work when I set the variable "style=null"!
But when I click a certain category, my map does not get reloaded?

I use the following code to click and reload my map:

```
$('#legend ul > li > ul > li').click(function(){
      if($(this).attr('data-hidden')==='false'){console.log('in conditie'); $(this).attr('data-hidden', 'true');$(this).addClass('enabled');} 
      else {$(this).attr('data-hidden', 'false');$(this).removeClass('enabled');}

      $('li').each(function(){
        hiddenArray[$(this).attr('data-name')] = $(this).attr('data-hidden');

      })
      map.renderSync();
    });
```

The map.renderSync() doesnt seem to do anything to my map?

Comment: There are a few similar and/or related questions on gis stack exchange [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80841/filter-vector-layer-features) and also [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34562/how-to-show-vector-features-in-openlayers-after-hiding-it). Hopefully they can shed some light on your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but because I am using the version 3,9 these examples do not help in my case :(

Comment: But **when** this should be happen?

Comment: I have a sidebar where you can click on some categories: e.g. clothing shops.

Comment: When you click on a category, a part of a layer has to become visible. Because I can set a different styling per category, I hoped I could also hide a part of the layer based on the category in my sidebar.

Comment: Maybe it's easier if you have a layer for each category, then you use `layer.setVisible(true/false)`.

Comment: I can't. I get a GeoJSON that has to be used for multiple pages and contains different categories. So I have to use the same JSON for multiple categories...

Comment: See if helps ... http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/8hgxyayp/

Comment: @Abayob did you see the fiddle I posted?

Comment: Hey Jonatas, sorry extremely busy today! Yes I did and it was an amazing help to get my problem fixed! Maybe post it as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments the logic would be:

Read the features from `GeoJSON` and add the features to different `ol.layer.Vector` based on a property called here `category`:

```
// Read from GeoJSON and add to different layer
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

features.forEach(function(feature) {
    var category = feature.get('category');
    var layer = thisLayerExists(category);
    if(layer) {
        //just add feature
        layer.getSource().addFeature(feature);
    } else {
        //add layer to map
        layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            name: category,
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [feature]
            }),
            style: point_style
        });
        map.addLayer(layer);
    }
});
```

And if you want to show only a `layer` that match to a given `category`:

```
function showCategory(category){
    var layers = map.getLayers();
    layers.forEach(function(layer){
        //discard layers other than ol.layer.Vector
        if(layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector){
            if(layer.get('name') == category){
                layer.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                layer.setVisible(false);
            }        
        }
    });
}
```

See missing `variables` and `functions` on [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/8hgxyayp/).

Comment: Is it correct that you can only use the following code for points and not for polygons? "var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geojsonObject, {
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});" I am getting errors when I try to use it for polygon data?

Comment: You can use for polygons. Maybe the error is because of style (`ol.style.Circle`). Try to remove the style from layer.